# Android GLSurfaceView pinch to zoom

Tags: android, opengl-es, zooming, glsurfaceview, pinchzoom

I am trying to implement pinch-to-zoom in GLSurfaceview and can't get it to work.
I know how to zoom into the center of the picture, that is easy (**the sample I am posting already does pinch-to-zoom to center of the image**). But I don't know how to take the finger coordinates into account.

The project itself is a gallery app so I don't need any fancy 3D rotation. I need to find out **how to zoom into the part of the image based on the pinch-to-zoom gesture**. Quite probably this could be a question of 3-5 lines of code, but I failed to find the right way to do this.

That means that the scene matrix is not only translated in the Z axis for zooming but also translated (moved) by a certain deltaX and deltaY ammount - to keep the point you are enlarging at it's place.

My scene is set-up like this:

(render mode is set to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)

```
    // Screen size (in screen pixels.
    private int mViewportWidth;
    private int mViewportHeight;
    // Rectangle for render area.
    private RectF mViewRect = new RectF();

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        mViewportWidth = width;
        mViewportHeight = height;

        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        mViewRect.top = 1.0f;
        mViewRect.bottom = -1.0f;
        mViewRect.left = -ratio;
        mViewRect.right = ratio;

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 20f, (float) width / height, .1f, 100f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

The drawing area **where the pinch-to-zoom** should be implemented:

```
@Override
public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    //Pinch-To-Zoom transformation should be implemented here
    //code below doesn't work
    gl.glTranslatef(-delta.x,-delta.y, -currentScale);

    //the drawing is done here
    //...
}
```

I get the the middle point between pinch gesture and scale in a method in the same render class:

```
private float currentScale = 6f;
/**
 * 
 * @param scaleAbsolute - scale value from ScaleGestureListener
 * @param focusX - X coordinate of pinch-to-zoom gesture in screen coordinates
 * @param focusY - Y coordinate of pinch-to-zoom gesture in screen coordinates
 */
public void zoom(float scaleAbsolute, float focusX, float focusY) {
    //the initial value of currentScale is 6f and by zooming in, we are decresing this value
    //currentScale is used as the Z value (so lower number = bigger zoom)
    currentScale = currentScale / scaleAbsolute;

    //Keep track of deltaX/deltaY here? How?

}
```

I think that a global deltaX and deltaY value should be added, but I don't know how to calculate the X,Y shift based on the current zoom level.

Here is a helper function that translated screen coordinates to scene coordinates:

```
/**
 * Translates screen coordinates into view coordinates.
 */
public void translate(PointF pt) {
    pt.x = mViewRect.left + (mViewRect.width() * pt.x / mViewportWidth);
    pt.y = mViewRect.top - (-mViewRect.height() * pt.y / mViewportHeight);
}
```

Comment: So the code's showing an image in its entirety, and now the user taps somewhere and the pinch-to-zoom should occur? There's anything more fancy involved?

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. Pinch to zoom in this code always zooms into the center of the image, no matter at which position you do the pinch-to-zoom gesture. The standard pinch-to-zoom should work as this: " Each of your two fingers should act as an "anchor" on the image - once the two fingers are pressed on the screen, the points on the image underneath each finger should stay stationary relative to their respective finger." (http://goo.gl/jdlG1)

Comment: Thanks for the info; I think I've confused this with "tap-to-zoom"...

Comment: Hi Daniel, have you had any luck with this? I'm trying to achieve the same thing. How are you reading your pinch gesture?

Comment: Hello, yes - I have finally managed to do the pinch-to-zoom on GLSurfaceView. I will post the answer today. I am reading the pinch gesture with ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener, this will handle the gesture for you.

Comment: @DanielNovak I'd be grateful if you'd provide me with the answer to this. Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this problem, please share your code